# Pan Gesture for UITableViewCell for whole row and do action at end of gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I need pan gesture like editingStyle in Swift, but I need this gesture for whole row and on end of gesture do action, which delete the cell.

I don't know, how to do it, because I am beginner. I know, that I must use UIGestureRecognizer, but I don't know how to do with that. I found some options, but all of that was only for delete without animation and I need animation and background for swiping.

I have only this code for show dynamic data:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TasksCell", for: indexPath) as! TasksCell

    let arrayTasks = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.taskName.text = arrayTasks.content

    return cell
}
```

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView Delegate method to delete row. No need to use Pan Gesture. Please try this

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   if editingStyle == .delete
   {
      yourArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
      yourTableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Comment: I using it, but I want to Gesture for swiping without tap with animation on whole cell.